# What does gdb change in debugged program behaviour w.r.t. `accept()` and `close()`

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, gdb

I've been chasing a problem: on exit application hangs, but when you debug it all is good. It boiled down to a wrong assumption made by someone 15 years ago, specifically he assumed that if one thread is waiting in `accept()` -- closing that handle in another thread will cause `accept()` to fail. Some of process unwinding code hinged on this assumption (and I know this assumption is not correct).

Question: why this assumption holds when program is being debugged? Precisely what changes in execution environment?

**Edit:** observed in CentOS 7

**Edit 2:** I know it is a UB and I need to fix it. My question is not "what to do?" but "why it happens?". I am curious because ability to sense debugger via side effects like this one is pretty cool and one day may came handy.

**Edit 3:**

I've discovered that if your process have a signal handler installed and (after closing fd) you send that signal (via `pthread_kill()`) to thread currently sleeping in `accept()` -- that call always immediately returns (with `EBADF` error). Doesn't matter what your handler is doing (as long as it returns). It looks like signal delivery causes thread to wake up, interrupt `accept()` and restart it (at which point it checks if related file "handle" is good and exit with error).

I am not encouraging to rely on this behavior, but propose a possible explanation to original question -- maybe `gdb` periodically wakes up every thread with some signal? Or being `ptrace`d means kernel (for some reason) will periodically wake up every thread "as if" it was interrupted by a signal?

Comment: You have a bug causing undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: It may be benign, or harmful, depending on circumstances. Adding debug code changes the game. Don't waste time trying to understand why UB sometimes works: fix the code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know and it isn't my code :)

Comment: @C.M. If you know - why would you ask? Undefined is undefined.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've updated my question to highlight the nature of my question

Comment: Suppose that the UB accidentally overwrites a local variable that was previously initialised. The program then crashes. Now, if you add debugger code, and the layout of the stack frame changes, the UB might accidentally overwrite a different local variable that has *not yet* been initialised. The program survives, (although there is something still missing, because the UB did not do what was intended).

Comment: @WeatherVane there was no "debugger code" added here, all that changed is that debugger attached to the app. `accept()` and `close()` innards are in kernel and (maybe) in libc. I'd like to understand why attaching a debugger causes related parts of kernel and/or libc to change their behavior in such way that it is observable by user code.

Comment: Debugging generates different code. You don't release code that contains debugging information. However it you are running *exactly the same code* then the debugger still makes a difference: [the observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)).

Comment: "why it happens?" is without interest when you talk about undefined behavior

Comment: @WeatherVane: Debugging affects runtime behavior, but not code.  In C (unlike say C#), none of source code, machine code, or microcode are changed by the debugger.  The changes in behavior are from installing callbacks -- the hooks for ptrace are already present in the kernel code the program calls, but now the syscalls find that the ptrace hooks are non-empty, and execute them.

Comment: @Stargateur I disagree. It is interesting to know how debugging may affect behaviour of your code. At the minimum understanding debugger's principles will make you a better system programmer. I bet it has smth to do with `ptrace()` implementation in Linux kernel -- somehow it causes `accept()` thread to wake up on `close()` executed in another thread even though I am not stepping through the code instruction-by-instruction (i.e. there are no signals that may interrupt `accept()`). For pure "application" developer, yes -- this info probably doesn't provide with a lot of value.

Comment: Both outcomes were always possible with the code because this is a race condition. Debugging just changed it from happening to do one thing all or most of the time to happening to do another thing all or most of the time. This is a common side-effect of debugging, unfortunately.

Comment: Now even if closing a FD was guaranteed to stop all syscall using it immediately, that's still a bad idea: by design you can't know what other threads are doing with the FD when you are closing it to wake-up those using it; you also can't prevent yet other threads from reusing the same FD number. Closing a FD means you promise to stop using it and makes it available for reuse. The bad FD error is a courtesy (unlike errors such as device full or IO error which indicates a problem with the current state of the system.): it indicates a design problem with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`ptrace` man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html):

> **Signal injection and suppression**
>
> After signal-delivery-stop is observed by the tracer, the tracer
>      should restart the tracee with the call
>
> ```
>    ptrace(PTRACE_restart, pid, 0, sig)
> ```
>
> where PTRACE_restart is one of the restarting ptrace requests.  If
>      is 0, then a signal is not delivered.  Otherwise, the signal sig
>      is delivered.  This operation is called signal injection in this man‐
>      ual page, to distinguish it from signal-delivery-stop.
>
> The sig value may be different from the WSTOPSIG(status) value: the
>      tracer can cause a different signal to be injected.
>
> Note that a **suppressed signal still causes system calls to return
>      prematurely.  In this case, system calls will be restarted**: the
>      tracer will observe the tracee to reexecute the interrupted system
>      call (or restart_syscall(2) system call for a few system calls which
>      use a different mechanism for restarting) if the tracer uses
>      PTRACE_SYSCALL.  Even system calls (such as poll(2)) which are not
>      restartable after signal are restarted after signal is suppressed;
>      however, kernel bugs exist which cause some system calls to fail with
>      EINTR even though no observable signal is injected to the tracee.

In my case termination logic starts with a delivery of a signal (that gets intercepted by gdb) and then passed injected into process being traced. `strace`-ing `gdb` produces:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, 2274, 0x7f0c9d0ee2e0, [0x7f0ca013ab80]) = 0      <-- gdb woke up to SIGTERM directed at tracee
ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, 2274, 8*SS + 8, [0x7f0ca013a8c0]) = 0
ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, 2274, 0, 0x7ffdb4f2c3a0) = 0
...
ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, 2338, 0x1, SIG_0)   = 0
ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, 2274, 0x1, SIGTERM) = 0     <-- SIGTERM is delivered to a thread chosen by kernel
...
ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, 2276, 0x1, SIG_0)   = 0     <-- all other threads are restarted
...
```

note that this is not enough to explain behavior fully because thread sleeping in `accept()` can restart syscall before other thread closes file descriptor.

But `strace` log is choke-full of similar sequences of commands (`PTRACE_PEEKTEXT` followed by ever-reducing number of `PTRACE_CONT`). What happens here is `gdb` wakes up on every thread termination, pulls some data out of tracee and restarts (remaining) threads, causing syscalls to be restarted. I.e. as threads exit one after another, each remaining thread gets stopped and restarted multiple times eventually causing `accept()` to be restarted **after** file descriptor is closed by another thread. In fact it is guaranteed to happen because said thread exits after closing it.